# Writing to SD card arduino

Tags: c++, c, arduino, sd-card

I'm having some troubles with my Arduino. I'm trying to make a dynamic name for my file and transform it to char array like I saw on some post from this website.

Here's how I wrote my function:

```
void writeSD()
{ 
  DateTime dt = RTC.now();

  String temp = "DIVE";
  temp += dt.day();
  temp += dt.month();
  temp += dt.year();
  temp += ".txt";

  Serial.println(temp);

  char filename[temp.length()+1];
  temp.toCharArray(filename, sizeof(filename));
  myFile = SD.open(filename, FILE_WRITE);  

  if (myFile) {
    Serial.print("Writing to txt file...");
    myFile.print(dt.day(), DEC);
    myFile.print('-');
    myFile.print(dt.month(), DEC);
    myFile.print('-');
    myFile.print(dt.year(), DEC);
    myFile.print(' ');
    myFile.print(dt.hour(), DEC);
    myFile.print(':');
    myFile.print(dt.minute(), DEC);
    myFile.print(':');
    myFile.print(dt.second(), DEC);
    myFile.println();
    myFile.close();
    Serial.println("done.");
  } else {
    Serial.println("error opening txt file");
  }
}
```

I'm only having `"error opening txt file"` and I don't know why. The name of my file is correct and appears like this when I print it on the console : `DIVE652014.TXT`

Comment: I don't know for sure if it's the cause of the problem, but you never actually NUL-terminate `filename`. If the compiler doesn't automatically initialize the array to all zeros, then the `SD.open()` call will see the filename followed by whatever garbage happens to come after it in memory.

Comment: You print out `temp`, but not `filename`. Try printing `filename` to check that the character array representation of the string is what you expect. You should also do as Andrew recommends: `filename[temp.length()] = '\0';`

Comment: When I print the file name I get the exact same thing as the temp value.
I tried the `filename[temp.length()] = '\0';` but I got an error `error: variable-sized object 'filename' may not be initialized`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out why that wasn't working when I read more precisely the documentation about the SD breakout board from Adafruit :

> The SD card library does not support 'long filenames' such as we are
>   used to. Instead, it uses the 8.3 format for file names, so keep file
>   names short! For example IMAGE.JPG is fine, and datalog.txt is fine by
>   "My GPS log file.text" is not!

So I had 10 chars but it only accepts 8 chars in the filename.

Thanks for trying to help me ! :)